# ¿Cómo acceder a los valores de un atributo en un campo?

Tags: c#, .net

Asumiendo que tengo el siguiente atributo:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class Unique : Attribute
{
    public bool IsUnique {get;set;}
    public Unique(bool x) { IsUnique = x; }
}
```

Y el campo en el que quiero implementar dicho atributo es:

```
public class TablaUsuarios
{
    [Unique(true)]
    public int ID;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor de la propiedad `IsUnique` del atributo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso en particular (versión aún mas corta y legible, gracias a Leandro Tuttini) y asumiendo que el atributo `Unique` existe 0 o 1 vez en el campo `ID`. Además si el atributo no está presente en el campo `ID` devolverá null

```
Unique uniqueAttribute = (Unique)typeof(TablaUsuarios)
                            .GetField("ID")
                            .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Unique));

bool? unique = uniqueAttribute?.IsUnique;
```

**Nota**: Esta solución usa la sintaxis de C# 6. De lo contrario la úlitma línea es equivalente a esta:

```
bool? unique = uniqueAttribute != null ? uniqueAttribute.IsUnique : (bool?)null;
```

Comment: Esta solución es particularmente más cómoda cuando solo quiero acceder a una propiedad en especifico, pero el codigo de Leandro Tuttini es práctico en listas y arreglos, no?

Comment: La primera versión del código de Leandro recorre los campos de TablaUsuario y luego por cada campo recorre sus atributos. No tiene que ver con listas o arreglos

Comment: Oh ya! No lo vi completamente, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo la clase puedes usar Reflection para acceder al atributo.

[Accessing Attributes by Using Reflection (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx)

[Accessing Custom Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Si obtienes el `typeof` de la clase podrias obtener las propiedades de esta y luego los atributos

```
Type t = typeof(TablaUsuarios);

var fields = t.GetFields();

foreach(var field in fields)
{
    foreach (ver attr in field.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    { 
        //aqui recorres los atributos de las propiedades 
    }
}
```

Otra alternativa mas corta

```
Type t = typeof(TablaUsuarios);

var result = (Unique)t.GetField("ID").GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(x=> x.GetType() == typeof(Unique));

bool isunique = result.IsUnique;
```